# How to calculate a weighted sum in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

I have the following data.frame:

```
A1  A2  EFF       FRQ      G1  G2
A   G   0.0125    0.4578   A   G
T   C   0.0143    0.1293   C   C
T   C   -0.017    0.8984   T   T
A   G   -0.018    0.8945   A   G
A   G   -0.009    0.8652   A   A
A   G   0.0001    0.3931   G   G
```

The effects (EFF) and the frequency (FRQ) are with respect to A1. I would like to calculate the summed effects of my G1 and G2. For example in the first row, if G1 = A1, then its effect is 0.0125. However, if G1 = A2, then I want to flip the sign of the effect and make it -0.125. If G2 = A1, I want G2's effect to be 0.0125. If G2 = A2 then I want G2's effect to be -0.125. I'm wanting to create a column "G1+G2 Effects".

In the first row, since G1 = A2, G1's effect is 0.0125. Since G2 = A2, G2's effect is -0.0125. Thus, in the new column "G1+G2 Effects", the sum would be 0. In second row, G1 = A2, so G1's effect is -0.0143, and G2 = A2 as well, so G2's effect is also -0.0143. The "G1+G2 Effects" column would thus read: -0.0286.

Here is what I want my output to look like:

```
    A1  A2  EFF       FRQ      G1  G2  G1+G2_Effects
    A   G   0.0125    0.4578   A   G   0
    T   C   0.0143    0.1293   C   C   -0.0286
    T   C   -0.017    0.8984   T   T   -0.034
    A   G   -0.018    0.8945   A   G   0
    A   G   -0.009    0.8652   A   A   -0.018
    A   G   0.0001    0.3931   G   G   -0.0002
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you are just counting the number of times G1 or G2 matches A1 minus the number of times G1 or G2 matches A2, and multiplying that number by EFF. You can do this with arithmetic operators in R:

```
dat$G1G2Effect <- with(dat, ((G1==A1) + (G2==A1) - (G1==A2) - (G2==A2))*EFF)
dat
#   A1 A2     EFF    FRQ G1 G2 G1G2Effect
# 1  A  G  0.0125 0.4578  A  G     0.0000
# 2  T  C  0.0143 0.1293  C  C    -0.0286
# 3  T  C -0.0170 0.8984  T  T    -0.0340
# 4  A  G -0.0180 0.8945  A  G     0.0000
# 5  A  G -0.0090 0.8652  A  A    -0.0180
# 6  A  G  0.0001 0.3931  G  G    -0.0002
```

Data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="A1  A2  EFF       FRQ      G1  G2
A   G   0.0125    0.4578   A   G
T   C   0.0143    0.1293   C   C
T   C   -0.017    0.8984   T   T
A   G   -0.018    0.8945   A   G
A   G   -0.009    0.8652   A   A
A   G   0.0001    0.3931   G   G", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
  zz = '
    A1  A2  EFF       FRQ      G1  G2
    A   G   0.0125    0.4578   A   G
    T   C   0.0143    0.1293   C   C
    T   C   -0.017    0.8984   T   T
    A   G   -0.018    0.8945   A   G
    A   G   -0.009    0.8652   A   A
    A   G   0.0001    0.3931   G   G
    '


df$cEFF = NA
df$cEFF = ifelse(as.character(df$G1) == as.character(df$A1), df$EFF, -df$EFF) +
          ifelse(as.character(df$G2) == as.character(df$A2), -df$EFF, df$EFF)

df

  A1 A2     EFF    FRQ G1 G2    cEFF
1  A  G  0.0125 0.4578  A  G  0.0000
2  T  C  0.0143 0.1293  C  C -0.0286
3  T  C -0.0170 0.8984  T  T -0.0340
4  A  G -0.0180 0.8945  A  G  0.0000
5  A  G -0.0090 0.8652  A  A -0.0180
6  A  G  0.0001 0.3931  G  G -0.0002
```

Answer (score 1):

a simple ifelse condition

```
> so$t1=ifelse(so$G1==so$A1,so$EFF,-so$EFF)+ifelse(so$G2==so$A1,so$EFF,-so$EFF)
> so
  A1 A2     EFF    FRQ G1 G2      t1
1  A  G  0.0125 0.4578  A  G  0.0000
2  T  C  0.0143 0.1293  C  C -0.0286
3  T  C -0.0170 0.8984  T  T -0.0340
4  A  G -0.0180 0.8945  A  G  0.0000
5  A  G -0.0090 0.8652  A  A -0.0180
6  A  G  0.0001 0.3931  G  G -0.0002
```